# Table variable name duplication error when trying to plot iris dataset

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've been trying to plot the iris data points of each combination of two dimensions of the four dimension dataset which contains the sepal length, sepal width, petal length and petal width. I tried to follow the documentation written in [Fuzzy C-Means Clustering for Iris Data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fuzzy-c-means-clustering-for-iris-data.html#irisfcm-1) though, I've been getting errors such as 'Error using load Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file iris.dat
"Iris-setosa".' when I tried to type load iris.dat in the command window.

This is what I've written so far:

```
iris = readtable('iris.dat');
setosa = iris(1:50,:);
versicolor = iris(51:100,:);
virginica = iris(101:150,:);
obsv_n = size(iris, 1);

Characteristics = {'sepal length','sepal width','petal length','petal width'};
pairs = [1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 2 3; 2 4; 3 4];
h = figure;
for j = 1:6
    x = pairs(j, 1);
    y = pairs(j, 2);
    subplot(2,3,j);
    plot([setosa(:,x) versicolor(:,x) virginica(:,x)],[setosa(:,y) versicolor(:,y) virginica(:,y)], '.');
    xlabel(Characteristics{x});
    ylabel(Characteristics{y});
end
```

The only issue I have, is the line of the plot command which gives me 'Error using askisi1_5 (line 14)
Duplicate table variable name: 'Var1'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have the Fuzzy Logic Toolbox, I do have the Statistics & ML Toolbox, which provides a file called 'fisheriris.csv' that can be opened with `readtable()`. I suspect all you need to do in your case is to invoke `table2array()` before concatenating columns with the same variable name from different table arrays (i.e. before doing stuff like `[setosa(...,n) versicolor(...,n) ...]`):

```
iris = readtable('fisheriris.csv');
setosa = iris(1:50,:);
versicolor = iris(51:100,:);
virginica = iris(101:150,:);

Characteristics = {'sepal length','sepal width','petal length','petal width'};
setosa = table2array(setosa(:,1:end-1));
versicolor = table2array(versicolor(:,1:end-1));
virginica = table2array(virginica(:,1:end-1));

pairs = [1 2; 1 3; 1 4; 2 3; 2 4; 3 4];
h = figure;
for j = 1:6
    x = pairs(j, 1);
    y = pairs(j, 2);
    subplot(2,3,j);
    plot([setosa(:,x) versicolor(:,x) virginica(:,x)], [setosa(:,y) versicolor(:,y) virginica(:,y)], '.');
    xlabel(Characteristics{x});
    ylabel(Characteristics{y});
end
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! It took me hours to even be able to save certain parts of the iris table into the variables, since I am quite a newbie into using matlab for analytics.